# HTML in SVG as SVG

Tags: html, svg, symbols

Recently started working with html in SVG. 
The code works fine FireFox but Chrome does not display the div content.

Can you please help me sort this issue. Here is a sample code that should show div content as "MY DIV" and an Airport symbol.

The code is saved as my_div.svg

Thanks in advance.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full"   viewport-fill="red">
        <defs>  
            <!-- My div -->
            <symbol id="my_div" viewBox="0 0 50 50" >
                <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red">
                    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background:none transparent;" width="50" height="50">
                        <div>MY DIV</div>
                    </body>
                </foreignObject>
            </symbol>

            <!-- Airport Symbol -->
            <symbol id="airport" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <path d="M 9.2,5 C 9.2,4.5 9.8,3.2 10,3 L 9,3 L 8,4 L 5.5,4 L 8,0 L 6,0 L 3,4 C 2,4 1,4.2 0.5,4.5 C 0,5 0,5 0.5,5.5 C 1,5.8 2,6 3,6 L 6,10 L 8,10 L 5.5,6 L 7.8,6 L 9,7 L 10,7 C 9.8,6.8 9.2,5.5 9.2,5 z "/>
            </symbol>

        </defs>

      <g fill="red"  transform="scale(18)"  >

          <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
            <use xlink:href="#my_div" width="5" height="5"/>
          </g>

          <g id="demo" transform="translate(0, 0)">
          <use xlink:href="#airport" x="10" y="0" width="5" height="5"/>
        </g>

     </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Looks like Chrome only has partial support for foreignObject - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html

Answer (score 1):

The SVG specs do not allow `<foreignObject>` content to be directly re-used with a `<use>` element.  The browsers have differed in their implementation of whether or not they allow you to `<use>` content that includes a `<foreignObject>` child--it isn't expressly forbidden by the specs, but it's somewhat circumventing the intent.

Firefox's implementation of `<use>` is basically a hidden clone of all the DOM elements, so they don't have any problem with cloning any type of content.   However, other browsers more strongly link the source and copy graphics, and don't have any copying mechanism for foreignObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Saved your code that you put here as an SVG and I received this:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start
>   of the document Below is a rendering of the page up to the first
>   error.

I fixed it by simply deleting the first line of code you provided.

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full"   viewport-fill="red">
        <defs>  
            <!-- My div -->
            <symbol id="my_div" viewBox="0 0 50 50" >
                <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red">
                    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background:none transparent;" width="50" height="50">
                        <div>MY DIV</div>
                    </body>
                </foreignObject>
            </symbol>

            <!-- Airport Symbol -->
            <symbol id="airport" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <path d="M 9.2,5 C 9.2,4.5 9.8,3.2 10,3 L 9,3 L 8,4 L 5.5,4 L 8,0 L 6,0 L 3,4 C 2,4 1,4.2 0.5,4.5 C 0,5 0,5 0.5,5.5 C 1,5.8 2,6 3,6 L 6,10 L 8,10 L 5.5,6 L 7.8,6 L 9,7 L 10,7 C 9.8,6.8 9.2,5.5 9.2,5 z "/>
            </symbol>

        </defs>

      <g fill="red"  transform="scale(18)"  >

          <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
            <use xlink:href="#my_div" width="5" height="5"/>
          </g>

          <g id="demo" transform="translate(0, 0)">
          <use xlink:href="#airport" x="10" y="0" width="5" height="5"/>
        </g>

     </g>
    </svg>
```

This worked in Chrome for me, (mac)

Comment: There was a space in the beginning of the code. Sorry for that. What version of Chrome displayed the inner div "MY DIV".

Answer (score 0):

I know it does not solve that error, but I would recommend using SVG without mixing HTML via foreignObject into it. Lags support from IE and could be solved as well with  and  svg elements. You can use css to style it like your text in the div box.

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_text.asp